# DownCasting Failing In Custom APEX Classes

Tags: apex, inheritance

I am developing a custom APEX application called Subscribe.

I have a parent wrapper class `SubscribeObject`:

```
public virtual class SubscribeObject {
    public SObject record;
    public SObject oldRecord;
    public SObject originalRecord;

    public SubscribeObject(SObject record, SObject oldRecord, Boolean editInPlace) {
        this.originalRecord = (Term_Segment__c) record;
        this.oldRecord = (Term_Segment__c) oldRecord;
        if(!editInPlace) { this.record = record.clone(true, true, true, false); }
    }
    public SubscribeObject() {}
}
```

Which is used to DRY up child wrapper classes for my SObjects such as this `TermSegementObjectClass` which wraps the `Term_Segment__c` SObject.

```
public class TermSegmentObject extends SubscribeObject {
    //Instance
    public Term_Segment__c record = (Term_Segment__c) super.record;
    public Term_Segment__c oldRecord = (Term_Segment__c) super.record;
    public Term_Segment__c originalRecord = (Term_Segment__c) super.record;
    public TermObject term;
    public SegmentObject segment;

    //Properties
    public Id Id {
        get { return record.Id; }
    }
    public Id termId {
        get { return record.term__c; }
    }
    public Id segmentId {
        get { return record.segment__c; }
    }
    public Decimal ARR {
        get { return record.arr__c; }
        set { record.arr__c = value; }
    }

    //Methods
    public void setARR() {
        arr = segment.ARR;
    }
}
```

I read the [casting documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) which seems to imply that I can do this:

```
Term_Segment__c record = new Term_Segment__c();
record.Start_Date__c = system.today();
TermSegmentObject tso = (TermSegmentObject) new 
SubscribeObject(record,NULL,True);
```

But whenever I run this code I get:

`System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type SubscribeObject to TermSegmentObject`

Any ideas on how I can get this downcasting to work?

If not, does anyone know a better way to setup this inheritance.  So I can abstract away the core subscribeObject behavior and have the child class focus on its specific application?

Comment: Have you gone through this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java This answer applies for Apex also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only downcast if the object is already an instance of the subclass. Since the parent class constructor returns an instance of the parent class, you can't downcast that.

You could use factory methods instead of constructors if you want the ability to return different subclasses from one statement. Or perhaps one method that accepts a generic SObject and uses the new switch/when statement to do different things based on the SObject type passed in.

Comment: I ended up using factory methods instead of constructors.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, you're allowed to up-cast (`SubscribeObject` <= `TermSegmentObject`), but not down-cast.

There are specific instances in Apex when you can down-cast, but it's not too common.

- Trigger context variables like `Trigger.new` are actually a `List<SObject>` that can be down-cast to list of a specific SObject type like `List<Account>`

  - When used inside of a trigger on that SObject, Salesforce implicitly down-casts trigger context variables for you
- If you start with a `List<Account>`, assign that list to a separate `List<SObject>`, you can downcast back to `List<Account>`

You've misread the documentation that you linked. The example given in that documentation is

```
public virtual class Report {

}

public class CustomReport extends Report {

}

  // Create a list of report objects
  Report[] Reports = new Report[5];

  // Create a custom report object
  CustomReport a = new CustomReport();

  // Because the custom report is a sub class of the Report class,
  // you can add the custom report object a to the list of report objects
  Reports.add(a);

  // The following is not legal:
  // CustomReport c = Reports.get(0);
  // because the compiler does not know that what you are
  // returning is a custom report.
  // You must use cast to tell it that you know what
  // type you are returning. Instead, get the first item in the list
  // by casting it back to a custom report object
  CustomReport c = (CustomReport) Reports.get(0);
```

Which primarily makes use of *up-casting*. The last line of the example is a special case of down-casting a list of a supertype (which is possible because the things stored in the `reports` list were initially of the subtype).

There's probably some formal type theory reason behind this, but that's beyond my knowledge (and beyond the scope of the question).

To achieve what you're looking to do, you'd want to create a constructor in your subclass, and use the `super()` keyword/method/thing to have your superclass handle the common constructor logic.

Best practice is also to keep class variables as restricted as possible. With that in mind, your classes would change to be something like this

```
public virtual class SubscribeObject {
    // Make private so that these variables can't be changed all willy-nilly
    //   by anything and everything
    private SObject record;
    private SObject oldRecord;
    private SObject originalRecord;

    public SubscribeObject(SObject record, SObject oldRecord, Boolean editInPlace) {
        this.originalRecord = (Term_Segment__c) record;
        this.oldRecord = (Term_Segment__c) oldRecord;
        if(!editInPlace) { this.record = record.clone(true, true, true, false); }
    }
    public SubscribeObject() {}

    // Make protected accessors for your subclasses
    // Apex methods are final by default, meaning they can't be overridden
    protected SObject getRecord(){
        return this.record;
    }

    protected SObject getOldRecord(){
        return this.oldRecord;
    }

    protected SObject getOriginalRecord(){
        return this.originalRecord;
    }
}
```

==

```
public class TermSegmentObject extends SubscribeObject {
    //Instance
    public Term_Segment__c record;
    public Term_Segment__c oldRecord;
    public Term_Segment__c originalRecord;
    public TermObject term;
    public SegmentObject segment;

    public TermSegmentObject(SObject record, SObject oldRecord, Boolean editInPlace) {
        // super needs to be the first thing called, if you use it
        super(record, oldRecord, editInPlace);

        // The accessor methods are inherited, and visible
        // The accessors return SObjects, so you'll need to explicitly downcast
        this.record = (Term_Segment__c) this.getRecord();
        this.oldRecord = (Term_Segment__c) this.getOldRecord();
        this.originalRecord = (Term_Segment__c) this.getOriginalRecord();
    }

    //Properties
    public Id Id {
        get { return record.Id; }
    }
    public Id termId {
        get { return record.term__c; }
    }
    public Id segmentId {
        get { return record.segment__c; }
    }
    public Decimal ARR {
        get { return record.arr__c; }
        set { record.arr__c = value; }
    }

    //Methods
    public void setARR() {
        arr = segment.ARR;
    }
}
```

Comment: typo in methods `getOldRecord`, `getOriginalRecord`  (BTW - very nice answer)

Comment: @DerekF I have tried your answer by replacing `Term_Segment__c` with `Contact` as I don't have `Term_Segment__c` object in my developer edition org but it is failing. Please look at this : https://gist.github.com/sfdcnoob/928dd0ca7b678ff79032f25bb83baac2  I have also included video. Thanks.

Comment: @javanoob The error messages you're getting in the dev console (Illegal assignment from SObject to {other object name here}) should provide a pretty good hint. Looks like you need to explicitly downcast in the `TermSegmentObject` constructor as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Aha, I missed that. It is simple. I added downcasting on those lines but it still fails. I updated my gist.

Comment: @DerekF It is still failing. I have updated my gist as per your answer. Please refer to this: https://gist.github.com/sfdcnoob/928dd0ca7b678ff79032f25bb83baac2

Comment: @javanoob It's probably better if you edit your question to include these updates and error messages. Also, most of the point of my answer here is that _you cannot downcast a superclass instance to a subclass instance in the way you're trying to do it_. The point of making the constructor in your subclass was to avoid the need to directly instantiate an instance of your superclass in the first place.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I was just curious as how calling super method in child class constructor as you suggested will solve OP’s question so wanted to try myself.

Comment: @javanoob oh, sorry, I confused you for OP there.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response.  Your code was super helpful in getting to the final decision, but I ended up using a factory pattern rather then constructors + super() to get the answer so I selected @charlesT's answer

Answer (score 0):

There is actually one workaround.

```
TermSegmentObject tso = (TermSegmentObject) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(new SubscribeObject(record,NULL,True)),TermSegmentObject.class);
```

This is of course very bad practise in terms of performance and readability, so you will have to figure out if it's worth it :)